# can a GraalVM app be deployed on a "regular" VM

Tags: java, graalvm

In order to gain the performance benefits offered by GraalVM, the application must be compiled using GraalVM's compiler. However, what's not clear to me is whether the application must also be executed by GraalVM, or whether it can be deployed to a "regular" VM (e.g. OpenJDK) in order to benefit from the improved performance?

Some additional details which may be relevant

- I'm using JDK 11
- The application in question only uses JDK languages, e.g. Java, Kotlin, Groovy
- The build artifact is a JAR file, i.e. GraalVM native images are **not** used

Comment: If you don't use **GraalVM Native Image**, then you don't benefit from better performance. The performance of executing bytecode is directly related to the VM which executes the bytecode.

Comment: @McPringle I don't think you're correct, surely the compiler itself also influences performance? See the "Run Java Faster" section of the GraalVM docs https://www.graalvm.org/why-graalvm/

Comment: @Antionio Dragos: You have two possibilities to make run a Java program faster with GraalVM: First, compile it to native code (Graal Native Image). Second, use the GraalVM as VM. But if you run your Java bytecode using a non-Graal-VM, it does not run faster. That is stated on the site you mentioned, too. :-)

Comment: @McPringle so is it the case that in order to benefit from GraalVM the code must be compiled *and* executed by GraalVM?

Comment: If you compile to bytecode, yes. If you compile to native code, no.

Answer (score 2):

If you have compiled your code with JVM Runtime mode, than you can run your application on any JVM. There is no compulsion of running the application with GraalVM.

If you have compile your code with Native Image compiler, than it will create a native executable binary which can be directly executed without usage of any JVM.

Comment: The specific case I'm asking about is when an application is compiled with GraalVM, but deployed as a JAR file. Must it be deployed to GraalVM in order to benefit from the optimizations performed by the GraalVM compiler.

Comment: Yes. The compiler which produces bytecode is limited to the standard. You can do a very simple test: Compile your application to bytecode using a GraalVM and a Java VM. Compare the bytecode. You mentioned a website as an answer to my comment. Citation: "GraalVM can run in the context of OpenJDK to make Java applications run faster with a new just-in-time compilation technology." Compiler != compiler. There are at least three compilers: The Java bytecode compiler, the just-in-time-compiler, and the native image compiler. The last two make the difference.

Answer (score 2):

GraalVM is based on OpenJDK with some extras; one of them is a state-of-the-art compiler.

The Graal compiler is very versatile; it is used to compile native images (AOT mode) but can also be used as a JIT compiler, replacing C2, which is the default shipped in OpenJDK.

The term compiler is a bit overloaded in this case. The traditional Java "compilers" e.g. javac/ecj, compile Java sources to bytecode. The "optimizing compilers" e.g. Graal and C2, compile bytecode to highly optimized assembly.

GraalVM uses a different "optimizing compiler" (Graal), which may indeed give some speedup compared to a vanilla OpenJDK (C2) but that's very dependent on your workload, you should always measure yourself.

Additional reference: [Twitter's Quest for a Wholly Graal Runtime by Chris Thalinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtgKmzgIh4c&t=1498s)